# Determine if CC system is realizable

Tags: computational-geometry

In *Axioms and Hulls*, Knuth defines the notion of a CC system, which is a generalization of Euclidean points in general position. While all such arrangements of points in the plane give a CC system, not all CC systems give an arrangement of points, i.e. are not *realizable*. Is there a polynomial-time procedure to determine if a given CC system is realizable?

Comment: Might it help if you gave a self-contained definition of a "CC system" and of "realizable"?  Or maybe any expert who knows enough to answer the question will already know those terms; I don't know.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CC_system